# Do loop with a switch case in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

//I need to add one to the total each time the error name is input. For example if I type "S" in the prompt, then it will add 1 to the total steering and if I type "W", it will add to wiper. The loop should run until i entered a null or zero value and calculate the total errors.

```
<html>
        <head><title>Charge Calculator</title></head>
        <body>
            <script type="text/javascript">
    
            
            //Declaring Variables
            var day;
            var data="";
            var steering = 0;
            var turbo =0;
            var wiper =0;
            day = prompt("Enter day: ","");
            var BR="<br/>";

            
    
            
            do
            {
            data = prompt("Enter Data: ","");
            data = input.nextLine();
            switch(data)
            {
            case 'S':
            steering++;
            break;      
            case 'T':
            turbo++;
            break;
            case 'W':
            wiper++;
            break;      
            }
        
            }
            while(data == "")   
            document.write("day: " +day +BR); //Display destination name
            document.write("Steering issue: " +steering +BR);
            document.write("turbo Issue: " +turbo +BR);
            document.write("wiper Issue: " +wiper +BR);
            
            </script>
        </body>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: So your prompts should be inside of the loop....

Comment: Tried that, still did not work

Comment: And what is `data = input.nextLine();` why are you overwriting the value in the prompt with that? My guess is now your console shows an error pointing to that line.

Comment: Could you please indent the code so that it becomes readable?

Answer (score 2):

There are many things to be improved in your code. Be aware that the `write()` expression will potentially destroy parts of your html-based page. Find out about DOM manipulation commands instead.

The following snippet demonstrates in a very short way how you could collect your inputs. I used your `prompt()` method simply to show that it can be done but I would always prefer a simple `input` field instead.

```js
const counts={s:0,t:0,w:0};

while (++counts[prompt("Please enter the error type code (s,t or w):").toLowerCase()]) {}

console.log("steering: "+counts.s+
      "\nturbo: "+counts.t+
      "\nwipers: "+counts.w);
```

Everything happens within the expression that calculates the result for the `while` condition: the input value is converted to lower case and then a property of the object `counts` will be incremented. This will only work (= return a "truthy" result) for already initialised properties like `s`, `t` or `w`. For all other cases an increment cannot be calculated, resulting in an "NaN" ("not a number") result. This will then end the while loop.

Comment: Clean and elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like recursion could be more appropriate solution here. Though @Cartsten's one looks absolutely ok also.

```js
function count() {
  const counts = {
    s: 0,
    t: 0,
    w: 0
  };

  const checkCounts = () => {
    let input = prompt(
      'Please enter the error type code (s,t or w):'
    ).toLowerCase();

    if (counts[input] !== undefined) {
      ++counts[input];
      return checkCounts();
    }
  };

  checkCounts();

  console.log(
    `steering: ${counts.s} \n turbo: ${counts.t} \n wipers: ${counts.w}`
  );
}

count();
```

Comment: recursion is a bad approach due to stack-limits

Comment: Not in this case